# ¿Cómo agregar campos de texto adicionales a la base de datos usando laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo un formulario de encuestas y necesito que los usuarios vayan añadiendo campos adicionales (opciones a votar dentro de la encuesta) y se guarden en la base de datos.

Ejemplo:

- Usuario A: Quiere una encuesta de votación con 3 campos.
- Usuario B: Quiere una encuesta de votación con 4 campos.

Soy nuevo en programación y no se cual es el nombre que se le da, además de como se hace lo que necesito, ya que solo he creado CRUD con tablas ya establecidas por mi en la migración.

Answer (score 0):

De antemano debes tomar en cuenta que no estarás almacenando cada respuesta adicional como parte del mismo modelo (las opciones no van a ser columnas dentro de la misma tabla de preguntas, que es lo que estás pensando).

En su lugar deberás tener dos modelos: `Pregunta` y `Opcion`, y en consecuencia dos tablas.

La tabla `preguntas` tendrá la información de la pregunta, y la tabla `opciones` guardará cada una de las opciones y tendrá una columna donde se almacenará el ID de la pregunta a la que pertenece cada opción.

Luego, cada vez que consultes una pregunta, invocarás también las opciones relacionadas, haciendo un JOIN de las tablas utilizando el ID de la pregunta como referencia.

De igual forma, cada vez que un usuario añada una opción nueva a una pregunta, se añadirá como un nuevo registro de la tabla `opciones` con el ID del registro correspondiente de la tabla `preguntas`. Así, cada pregunta podrá tener infinitas opciones.

¡Ésa es la idea general!

En adelante te recomiendo que revises las [relaciones "One To Many" de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) para saber cómo definir correctamente este problema, aunque antes deberás repasar un poco el concepto de [relaciones en bases de datos](https://styde.net/relaciones-entre-tablas-de-bases-de-datos/) para que entiendas por qué necesitas dos modelos.